# Spark: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed kmeans (mllib)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-analysis

I am trying to do a clustering aplicaction with kmeans.
My dataset is:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/ElectricityLoadDiagrams20112014#

I do not have much experience with spark, I have been working only a few months, the error occurs when I try to apply kmean.train which has a inputs: vector, num_cluster and iterations.

I am running locally, is it possible that my machine can not computing so much data?

The main code is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import scala.collection._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}

object Preprocesado {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Preprocesado").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._ 
    val sc = spark.sparkContext 

    val datos = spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", ";").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load("input.csv")
var df= datos.select("data", "MT_001").withColumn("data", to_date($"data").cast("string")).withColumn("data", concat(lit("MT_001 "), $"data"))
val col=datos.columns

for(a<- 2 to col.size-1) {
      var user = col(a)
      println(user)
      var df_$a = datos.select("data", col(a)).withColumn("data", to_date($"data").cast("string")).withColumn("data", concat(lit(user), lit(" "),  $"data"))
       df = df.unionAll(df_$a)
      }

val rd=df.withColumnRenamed("MT_001", "values")
val df2 = rd.groupBy("data").agg(collect_list("values"))

val convertUDF = udf((array : Seq[Double]) => {
  Vectors.dense(array.toArray)
})
val withVector = df2.withColumn("collect_list(values)", convertUDF($"collect_list(values)"))
val items : Array[Double] = new Array[Double](96)
val vecToRemove = Vectors.dense(items)
def vectors_unequal(vec1: Vector) = udf((vec2: Vector) => !vec1.equals(vec2))
val filtered = withVector.filter(vectors_unequal(vecToRemove)($"collect_list(values)"))
val Array(a, b) = filtered.randomSplit(Array(0.7,0.3))
val trainingData = a.select("collect_list(values)").rdd.map{x:Row => x.getAs[Vector](0)}
val testData = b.select("collect_list(values)").rdd.map{x:Row => x.getAs[Vector](0)}
trainingData.cache()
testData.cache()
val numClusters = 4
val numIterations = 20
val clusters = KMeans.train(trainingData, numClusters, numIterations)
clusters.predict(testData).coalesce(1,true).saveAsTextFile("output")


spark.stop()
  }
}
```

When I compile there is no errors.
Then I submit with:

```
spark-submit \
  --class "spark.Preprocesado.Preprocesado" \
  --master local[4] \
  --executor-memory 7g \
  --driver-memory 6g \
  target/scala-2.11/preprocesado_2.11-1.0.jar
```

The problem is in the clustering:
This is the error:

```
18/05/20 16:45:48 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 10.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 6347)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$.fastSquaredDistance(MLUtils.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$.fastSquaredDistance(KMeans.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$findClosest$1.apply(KMeans.scala:563)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$findClosest$1.apply(KMeans.scala:557)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$.findClosest(KMeans.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$.pointCost(KMeans.scala:580)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$initKMeansParallel$2.apply(KMeans.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$initKMeansParallel$2.apply(KMeans.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can I solve this error?

Thank you

Comment: This particular error is caused by inconsistent dimensions of the input data (input vectors have different lengths). Not related to the error but creating features with `rd.groupBy("data").agg(collect_list("values"))` doesn't look right.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have checked the length of the inputs vectors (trainingData) and all have the same length.
`trainingData.foreach(x => println(x.size))`

Comment: If you do not need to use a cluster, but run local, then consider alternatives to Spark. They may be a *lot* faster, in particular for kmeans.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are generating your DataFrame df and consequently df2 in the wrong way.
Maybe you are trying to do this:

```
case class Data(values: Double, data: String)
var df = spark.emptyDataset[Data]

df = datos.columns.filter(_.startsWith("MT")).foldLeft(df)((df, c) => {
                val values = col(c).cast("double").as("values")
                val data = concat(lit(c), lit(" "), to_date($"_c0").cast("string")).as("data")

                df.union(datos.select(values, data).as[Data]) 
    })


val df2 = df.groupBy("data").agg(collect_list("values"))
```

As i think, you only need two columns: *data* and *values*, but in the for loop you are generating a DataFrame with 140256 columns (one for each attribute) and maybe this is the source of your problems.

pd: sorry for my english!.